# I'm getting an error while scapring telegram with phone

Tags: python

I'm writing a telegram login code from my android phone with a telethone and I'm constantly getting the same async error, I couldn't find a solution:

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'UserMethods.is_user_authorized' was never awaited 
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events

class Scarping:
    def __init__(self):
        self.api_id = "id"
        self.api_has = "hash"
        self.phone = "phone"
        self.name = "name"

        self.client = TelegramClient(self.name, self.api_id, self.api_has)

        self.groups = []

    def connect(self):
        self.client.start
        if not self.client.is_user_authorized():
            self.client.send_code_requests(self.phone)
            self.client.sing_in(self.phone, int(input("code: ")))

if "__main__"==__name__:
    telegram = Scarping()
    telegram.connect()
```

I looked all the sample codes on google but nothing worked

Comment: I am not sure whether the line `self.client.start` is syntactically correct.

Comment: You never `await` the result of `is_user_authenticated`. The promise is always true